# msg.sender.call{value: 0.1 ether, gas: 1}(""): Why it doesn't fail? Shouldn't?

Tags: gas, hardhat, gas-limit

I'm making a simple test to force a transaction to be reverted, but it just doesn't happen.

I have this function where I intend to limit the `gas` to just 1.

```
contract MyContract {
    constructor() payable {}
    
    function pleaseFail(uint256 _guess) public {
        (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: 0.1 ether, gas: 1}("");
        require(sent, "Failed do send ether");
    }
}
```

I have a test just as simple as possible:

```
describe("Test fail", function () {
  it("Should fail", async function () {
    const FF = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract");
    const _f = await ff.deploy({ value: utils.parseEther("0.1") });
    await _f.deployed();

    _f.pleaseFail(7);
   }
}
```

However, when I execute the command line it just doens't fail. What am I missing? Is this some kind of expected behavior for Hardhat?

`npx hardhat test test/myFailure.ts`

Comment: `msg.sender.call{value: 0.1 ether, gas: 1}("")` You can also use gas:0. `msg.sender` isn't a contract so it doesn't consume gas

Comment: 0xSanson, I'm not sure if I got your point. As you can see in my comment at Priyanshu answer, when I change the value to 0.100000000000000001, the fail happens.

Comment: ok, I thought you were surprised that 1 gas was enough

Answer (score 1):

Please send the value slightly greater than `0.1` ether and also you have `ff.deploy` where it should be `FF.deploy` and please use assert statements to make sure it behaves as you wish.

Comment: Thanks, fren.
I've changed the value as you suggested and it's  failed as expected. I just didn't get it why:  `msg.sender.call{value: 0.100000000000000001 ether, gas: 1}("");`


PS: The `FF.deploy` was just a mistake when converting the variable names to post here

Answer (score 0):

```
    it("Should fail", async function () {
        const FF = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract");
        const _f = await FF.deploy({ value: utils.parseEther("0.1") });
        await _f.deployed();
    
        await _f.pleaseFail(7);
        /*await expect(_f.pleaseFail(7)).revertWith('Failed do send ether')*/
}
```